# What does "\" do at the end of a line of code?

Tags: ruby

In this method:

```
def look_deep (action, max_item_depth = 9, max_aspect_depth = 9)
   self.class.numbering_reset
   r = look_deeper \
    [] , #no context yet
   { #deep
     :root => id,
     :row => 0 ,
     :columns => {
       :names => Array.new,
       :cells => Array.new
     } ,
     :action => action ,
     :debug_log => ''
   } ,
    max_item_depth , #optional
    max_aspect_depth , #optional
    0 #item_depth
   @toy_debug = self.class.debug_map r
   r
 end
```

I don't understand what this means:

```
r = look_deeper \
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: just a line splitter

Comment: You need to ask whomever it was that wrote it, to use comments. Proper comments.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. “help me understand this” is too broad. I guess you are asking what it does, what it is syntactically. (In contrast to why the author used it here for example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html) you'll find:

> Ruby is a line-oriented language. Ruby expressions and statements are terminated at the end of a line unless the statement is obviously incomplete---for example if the last token on a line is an operator or comma. A semicolon can be used to separate multiple expressions on a line. *You can also put a backslash at the end of a line to continue it onto the next.* Comments start with `#' and run to the end of the physical line. Comments are ignored during compilation.

The examples associated with the continuation character are:

```
d = 4 + 5 +      # no '\' needed
    6 + 7

e = 8 + 9   \
    + 10         # '\' needed
```

(Emphasis is mine.)

Answer (score 2):

The \ character is known as an escape character.  It signals to ignore the next character, in this case the carriage return, or newline character.

It is used in several languages.  It is used in regular expression, Perl, etc. and not just Ruby.